# Is the comma in a variable list a sequence point?

Tags: c++, variables, comma-operator, sequence-points

In the following type of code is there a sequence point between each variable construction, or is the result undefined?

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++, c = a++;
```

I wasn't able to find in the standard a specific reference to a sequence point here. Does that mean it is undefined, or just that I failed in my search? The completion of an expression is a sequence point, but does the above initialization also count?

Comment: @Mark: Correct, the comma is a separator, not an operator in that situation. *Update:* Where did Mark go? :-S I'd hazard a guess that since it's a separator it is definitely a sequence point, but I'm eagerly waiting for an authoritative answer.

Comment: Since this universally considered bad practice why worry about it. Just put each declaration in a separate statement.

Comment: @Martin: I sometimes find it useful for making a variable and a pointer to it in one go, especially if the typename is really long: `MyVeryLongType::subclass::foo<Bar>::type x, * px = &x;`...

Comment: I always do stuff like `for(iterator b = begin(), e = end(); ..)` and I think it's fine. Just don't do side effects in the initializers.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Use two lines (don't be lazy). You will find almost universally that any company with coding guidelines will force you to re-write it anyway (get used to it). As litb mentions about the only place it is tolerated is in for(;;) where it is universally accepted as ok (bu never for doing what you do).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe behavior is well-defined because of **8[dcl.decl]/3**

> Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

Which is even additionally explained in a footnote as

> A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to the corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single
>   declarator. That is
>
> ```
> T D1, D2, ... Dn;
> ```
>
> is usually equvalent to
>
> ```
> T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;
> ```

Comment: +1: The word usually means that they may not be equivalent, for example, in this case: `struct S{}; S S, A;` (not equivalent to the ill-formed `S S; S A;`

Comment: +1, but take note that this is only half of the cake. Only 8p3 together with 1.9px seems to completely answer that (one could still argue that "int a = i++; int b = i++;" is UB because of a missing sequence point, if it weren't 1.9px to forbid this argument). Therefor I +1 both @Alan and your answer.

Answer (score 10):

As you suspect there is a sequence point after each initializer expression, because they're full expressions (1.9/16, 1.9/12).

Comment: Could you add whether the OP's example is equivalent to `int b = a++; int c = a++;`? *Update:* Never mind, Cubbi's answer nails it.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above seem to pertain to C++. Just to confirm, for C, ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 committee draft (September 7, 2007) Annex C, says:

> ```
> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3: [...]
> — The end of a full declarator: declarators (6.7.5);
> — The end of a full expression: an initializer (6.7.8); [...]
> ```

So the answer is the same:

> there is a sequence point after each initializer expression, because they're full expressions