# Is the order of assignment in a list of initialized variables undefined?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the comma in a variable list a sequence point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414030/is-the-comma-in-a-variable-list-a-sequence-point)

If I have the following code does the comma act as a normal sequence point, or is the behaviour undefined?

```
int i = 1, j = i;
```

*I don't actually plan to use this (our internal standard prohibits even `int i, j`) but I was curious and it prooved oddly tricky to google.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's well-defined:

#### 8. Declarators: [dcl.decl]

> 3) Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

And the note:

> 90) A declaration with several declarators is usually equivalent to
>   the corresponding sequence of declarations each with a single
>   declarator. That is
>
> `T D1, D2, ... Dn;`
>
> is usually equvalent to
>
> `T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;`
>
> where T is a decl-specifier-seq and each Di is an
>   init-declarator.

For completness (because the note says *usually*):

> The exception occurs when a name introduced by one of the declarators
>   hides a type name used by the dcl-specifiers, so that when the same
>   dcl-specifiers are used in a subsequent declaration, they do not have
>   the same meaning, as in `struct S { ... }; S S, T;` // declare two
>   instances of struct S`which is not equivalent to`struct S { ... }; S
>   S; S T; // error`

Comment: +1 that was a crazy-fast answer

Comment: You are the Flash my good sir!