# Does `int a = 0, b = a` have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, declaration, undefined-behavior

The question title says it all: do declarations of the form `int a = 0, b = a` have undefined behavior?

Comment: The next question would then be, does such a code row make any sense in any real-world scenario? Is there ever a reason why you would write this and not `int a=0; int b=0;`?

Comment: @Lundin When the value of `a` is the result of a function that you don't want to execute twice, which is my case. I need two copies of this value: one to output and one that I need to modify while doing some other computations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the comma in a variable list a sequence point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414030/is-the-comma-in-a-variable-list-a-sequence-point) and [Is the order of assingment in a list of initialized variables undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729962/is-the-order-of-assingment-in-a-list-of-initialized-variables-undefined?lq=1)...

Comment: @PaulManta What's wrong with `int  a = func(); int b = a;`?

Comment: @Lundin Nothing. But I was curious about the behavior of the other declaration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is well-defined. This is a declaration with two declarators, `a` and `b`. Each declarator has an initializer.

> Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

That is, the line is treated like:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
```

Comment: "analyzed separately" doesn't seem to indicated anything about sequencing at execution statement. Is there a stronger indication about this in the standard?

Comment: To answer my own comment, I think you need to quote 1.9/14 about the evaluation of full expressions being sequenced before the evaluation of subsequent full expressions. See comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6414247/19563.

Answer (score 8):

**No, there is no Undefined Behavior**.

Per Paragraph 8/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself

Also, as footnote 97 specifies:

> A declaration with several declarators is usually **equivalent to the corresponding sequence of declarations** each with a single
>   declarator. That is
>
> `T D1, D2, ... Dn;`
>
> is usually(*) equivalent to
>
> `T D1; T D2; ... T Dn;`

This means that `a` is initialized first, then `b` is initialized and assumes the value of `a`. Also notice that even if this was not the case, there has been [quite a long debate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub) over whether this would or would not be UB, and some consensus has been reached on this not being UB.

---

(*): As explained by Olaf Dietsche in the comments, the situations where this equivalence does *not* hold are mentioned later on in the same footnote.

Comment: Footnotes are not normative in ISO standard, so they don't specify anything at all, they are just informative text.

Comment: In addition to what Lundin said, the word "usually" doesn't give me any warm fuzzy feelings about sequence guarantees.

Comment: @Lundin: Footnotes are not normative, that's right. But they are often there to state things that you could otherwise infer from the Standard through more complex formal deductions. I was not able to carry out those deductions myself, but I thought this could be a relevant reference, at least as a declaration of intent.

Comment: @IronMensan The exceptions are stated in the same footnote and involve constructs reusing names `struct S ...; S S, T;` or using `auto i = 1, j = 2.0;`